# Writable System Revets to RO

Tags: root-access, permissions, system

I rooted with TWRP 3.2.1-0, installed SuperSU zip (later automatically updated) and added Busybox. I presently have three backups plus one of the EFS directory alone. The older one is some three weeks old. Since then I fight with this problem. Probably, I have done something wrong, but I can’t figure out what.

The problem is that I don’t really have root access, even if any type of root checker says that I do. Files on ES Explorer read `rw` each time I restore any of those backups, as I can see, but a couple of minutes later the CHMOD strangely changes by itself to what it is when a phone is not rooted, and writing permissions are gone. Chang CHMOD with a file manager has the same result, but showing `dwrx`. If I reboot I have `drw` everywhere, but no effect on root access as in any case, and in less than 2 minutes all root directories revert to their original permissions, except the `/system` directory, maintaining now `drwxrwxr-x`. This is very confusing and difficult to describe, but something is sure: the permissions change by themselves and I never have root access. However I had it before the first TWRP backup because I could install an application on `/system`.
I know little about adb commands, but I have used those that I found on other threads on this forum and elsewhere, and get some answers like `adbd cannot run as root in production builds for adb root`. I also tried the following command on both the TWRP terminal and a terminal emulator app, also both under u0227@jflte:/ and after entering SU:
`mount -o rw,remount /system`

Result under u0227@jflte:/      `Mount: Permission denied`

after entering SU here `tmp-mksh: Mount: not found`

Command   `/system/bin/mount -o remount,rw /system /system` 
Result:     `Permission denied`

#### More commands that I ran on adb on computer

`adb devices` 
Result:
`List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
4daf65fc        device`

`adb shell` 
Result: `shell@jflte:/ $ su
1|shell@jflte:/ $ #
1|shell@jflte:/ $ adb root
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found`

`mount -o remount,rw /system` 
Result: `mount: Permission denied`

`mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 /dev/block/actc /system` 
Result: `mount: Permission denied`

There are others that I tried, but this post is already so long...
Still, when I try to install any app with System Apps Installer or other as root, as I could before, I invariably get the same answer: Mounting error, Cannot mount system partition as Read/Write.

I found a few advices to use the command `cat /proc/mounts`  to find problems. I did, but I post a copy of the very long result after this text because I can’t find anything by myself. Perhaps it will help someone to help me.

The same happens now with the other slightly older backups that I restored, but at the beginning I even installed an application in the `/system`. Why has this changed? Could it have been from the latest updated SuperSU version, because I read on XDA Developers it has issues and recommend changing to an older version? I searched a lot and found many threads about this permissions problems but none changing like mine, and none solved. I wonder what the cause can be and. Why so many threads about the root permissions issue and not a single one solved?
Thank anyone for any welcome help. Sorry for being so long, but I really want to repair this issue and with so many threads about it I couldn't find just one solution.

Result from command `cat /proc/mounts`

`root@jflte:/ # cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/apnhlos /firmware vfat ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mdm /firmware-mdm vfat ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/efs /efs ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/hidden /preload ext4 ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persdata /persdata/absolute ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/data/media /mnt/shell/emulated sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
/data/privatemode /mnt/shell/privatemode sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,derive=none 0 0
/data/knox/sdcard /mnt/shell/knox-emulated sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,derive=none 0 0
tmpfs /storage/emulated tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=751,gid=1028 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:33 /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard vfat rw,dirsync,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/extSdCard /storage/extSdCard sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=unified 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated/0 sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated/legacy sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
root@jflte:/ #`

Comment: A lot of info, but you forgot the basics: Device name and Android version...

Comment: Galaxy S4. <br/>
5.0.1 stock. <br/>
It was not enough information after all, because it has been here for over two days. Would you like to help, please?

Comment: I avoid Samsung devices, therefore I don't have experience with them. However what I know: `adb root` will never work on most devices newer than Android 4. See [adb root does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477424). Anyway with your device I would recommend to install a current LineageOS instead of only rooting - Android 5 is pretty old...

Comment: It is not **only** rooting. I wanted to do it step by step, but was stopped on the way. I am starting to be convinced that the problem is on this latest SU version. I will try to find an older one and flash the zip with TWRP. Root did work on this phone about three years ago for nearly two. All I need is what I asked for and nothing else. Computer OSs last much longer. Guess why and how we are being stolen by manufacturers and carriers, mainly in the US, where almost only carriers sell phones locked and killing the warranty if you use your rirght to change the OS like w/any computer. Illegal.